# Neo4j database in a Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, neo4j

I have a servlet and want to connect to a Neo4j database. So that i can access the database from my application over Internet.
But the servlet gives an error? 
Am i doing something wrong?

Here is my servlet code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("Hello World");

GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\Sourav\\Desktop\\db1");
}
```

This is the error returned in the webpage.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory
hello.hello.doGet(hello.java:45)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: according to your log that GraphDatabaseFactory class can't be found, do you add the kernel jar to your buildPath

Comment: Yes i have added the neo4j-kernel-1.8.2.jar 
Another interesting thing is that I have the working database code in a java file. Now when i create a object of that class in the servlet, it still gives an error.
I am crating the object inside the doGet(). Is it right?

Comment: I don't why either, usually I use Spring neo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
I copied the Neo4j JAR files in Tomcat 7.0\lib  and it solved the problem completely!!!

Comment: So you found a workaround. But that didn't actually solve the problem. Your application cannot simply be moved to another Application Server. Are you using maven as build tool? If so, try adding the org.neo4j.neo4j dependency, which includes several packages including the one you need. Also, remove the jar from tomcat if you do this, or you might end up with a dependency conflict.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use Neo4j's REST api. That's the standard way to use Neo4j if you are accessing it over the internet (not embedded in your program).

You'll want to follow [this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server.html) which shows you how to set up Neo4j as a server that has a REST api.

Personally, I think it's a lot easier using it embedded in Java. If you're creating it as an embedded Java database, you should do something like this:

```
GraphDatabaseService dbService = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

However, you should only be doing that once when your program starts up. So instantiate that on program start up and just use a static reference to it. (Or better yet, use Spring and just autowire Neo4jOperations in wherever you need it. Or best of all, use [Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j)!)

Comment: So @CorayThan you say Spring Data Neo4j is a good option. I will have to look into this.
I tried with REST API, but there's a problem with TraversalDescription. The implementation has changed in 1.81. and therefore we cannot instantiate TraversalDescription.

Comment: I've been liking Spring Data Neo4j so far. It has a few limitations (no built-in lazy loading), but it has still saved me a fair bit of work.

Comment: You use RestTraversal.description() instead of TraversalDescription when you work with the REST server, you can also look into the java-rest-bindings: http://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .here are the steps-
Go to buildpath -> configure build path
select Deployment assembly
Make sure you have Ivy(maven) library in there. If not add it through add->java build path entries->ivy(or maven)

If you have added neo4j library externally(not through ivy/maven) then add that library in deployment assembly.
It should solve the problem